# Material Design on older versions Android

Tags: android

I have projects in **Eclipse**, using **Material Theme**, I want that this topic has been in the application, if used in **later** versions of Android. For example **S Converter**, or application from Google. Quite simply, you need to do in order to be compatible with previous versions.

Comment: What in the world did you just say? please edit your question to be more coherent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 21 of the AppCompat library introduced a Material theme for pre-21 devices.

First, you need to add the AppCompat library to your project.

Once you have done that, you just need to update your theme to extends from either `Theme.AppCompat` or `Theme.AppCompat.Light` like so:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Set your app's colors for the ActionBar and View widgets here -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/my_accent</item>
</style>
```

Finally, update your Activities to extend from AppCompat's `ActionBarActivity`.

Comment: just had to update the support library, thanks